# How to print out a string of a '&', equal to the length of a list

Tags: python, list

I want to print out a list of the character '&' as many times as there are in a given number. So if the number is 10, I want the result to be '&&&&&&&&&&&'

What I have done is turned the int into a list so I can better visualize what I want to perform.

```
def print_list_&(size):
    """super serious docstring"""
    result_1 = 1
    result_2 = size + 1
    result = list(range(result_1, result_2))
    return result
```

I'm stuck on where I go from here. This is university work so I'm better off with a push in the right direction than a straight answer.

Comment: Is `&` allowed in naming? ie. `def print_list_&(size):` I don't think so...

Comment: The "&" character isn't valid for Python identifiers. Valid characters are uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9. The [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/) add more Unicode characters.

Comment: im using the '&' character within a string rather than an identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'&' * 10` will give you `'&&&&&&&&&&'`. Therefore it seems you just need `'&' * size`.

Comment: Yea I kind of figured it out like 20 seconds after I asked the question. I feel both dumb and proud of myself, thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Python 2:

```
N = int(raw_input())
print '&' * N
```

Python 3:

```
N = int(input())
print ('&' * N)
```